# open neutral caused from changing water tank?

Tags: electrical

I had my water tank changed and since then my dish washer does not work. There is no power to it from the existing wire. Ihave since turned off the breaker to it changed it and nothing. There are no other outlets in the house that dont work with power off so i assume its the only appliance on this circuit. I have a 3 prong tester and I noticed that all my outlets show (open neutral) what the hay? its a 10 year old house. do i need an electrician?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. You say that most outlets work but the tester shows open neutral? This is impossible - nothing plugged into an outlet with an open neutral could work. Yes, I suggest you call an electrician.

Comment: You said you have since turned off the breaker and changed it? You changed the breaker? How do you know you have the correct breaker if you aren't getting any power to the dishwasher to begin with? Normally a dishwasher (especially in a newer house like yours) is on a separate breaker by itself.

Comment: Are you using a wireless Circuit Breaker Finder? I'd say you either aren't using it correctly, or it's defective.

Answer (score 5):

In short and to answer your immediate question-- yes, you most likely need an electrician to come perform troubleshooting. However, there seems to be some ambiguity here.

I'm going to make the assumption that "water tank" means 240V electric water 
heater? Did you install the new tank or was it installed by a professional? If all of this happened immediately after the installation, I suggest having your installer come back to verify the installation before hiring anyone else.

It sounds like your receptacle tester is not telling you the full truth. You said your receptacles work, but they physically cannot with an open neutral-- you would have an open circuit and be in the dark. However, you can have an open neutral and still have a live "hot" wire, so don't take anything for granted.

If the neutral is indeed open on *all* of your receptacles, that would most likely indicate a problem at your breaker panel. This would bring us back around full circle to calling an electrician.